# Removing the blue resolution selector bar

Tags: virtocommerce

This might sound a bit silly but I can't remove the bottom bar that allows you to select the device the website is being displayed on. 
I understand i need to remove the unordered list from the index.html file and make the iframe that contains the store be the main focus, but even though i can indeed remove the list, the space that it occupied will still be there, just fully white. I'm using VirtoCommerce 1.13

Anyone got any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it:

Comment the unordered list from the index.html that contains the screen size options.

Edit lines 5 and 8 in the **main.js** file that's under **responsive>js** to remove the '-47'.
That should do it.